# The distance between point $\ P $ and line $\ell $

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have point $P $ outside of some line $\ell $ . How do I show that if $u $ is a vector going out from the line $\ell$ to the point $p$ and $v$ is parallel to $\ell$ then the distance between $P$ to $\ell$ is $$\frac{\lVert u \times v \rVert }{\lVert v\rVert} $$

Now even when I tried to draw it I couldn't see how exactly is this statement true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lVert u \times v \rVert$ is the area of the parallelogram with sides $u$ and $v$. The area of a parallelogram is equal to the length of its base ($v$) and its height $PC$. And the height is equal to the distance from the vertex not in the base ($P$) to the line that includes the base  ($\ell$).[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

The distance is
$$
\lVert u\rVert \sin\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and the line direction $v$.
$$
\lVert u\rVert \sin\theta = 
\lVert u \times \hat{v}\rVert =
\frac{ \lVert u \times  v\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}
$$